# how to make my initial workbook activate based on a full pathname

Tags: vba, excel

i have the following code, need it to work:

```
Sheets("BigMaster").Range("A1:z999").Copy
Windows("Z:\Viewpoint\Viewpoint Import\Programs\SheetsForConstructionAndImportingIntoViewpoint - FROZEN.XLSM").Activate
Sheets("BigMaster").Range("A1").Paste
```

its failing on the activate command. how come?

i have tried to shorten the workbook name but it is still not working. i definitely have the right path though, i took it with windows explorer.

basically i need to copy from bigmaster on my current book to the bigmaster on the activate clause. but i get an error 9 subscript out of range.

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix this macro

Comment: You don't need to use `Activate`. I ***highly*** suggest reading, and applying, [how to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the destination workbook is open - if it's not then you first need to open it

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BigMaster").Range("A1:z999").Copy _
  Workbooks("SheetsForConstructionAndImportingIntoViewpoint - FROZEN.XLSM"). _
    Sheets("BigMaster").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Note that since the sheets (`"BigMaster"`) is the same name in both workbooks. You may want to avoid `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BigMaster")...` just in case the `"SheetsForConstructionandIMportingIntoViewPoint- FROZEN.XLSM"` is the activesheet.